# Ethereum transaction taking forever? From MEW to IDEX wallet

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, transaction-propagation

new to IDEX and mew, but I hooked up my MEW wallet to IDEX and than deposited ethereum to my IDEX wallet with the default gwei,

just wondering why its taking so long? its been 4 hours and no progress has been made, currently sitting at 1100 confirmations...

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde4269e9d46d44371464600162fcb9dbcf7d6f15bd622bfd786da6b9edfa1710

Answer (score 1):

The transaction was properly confirmed in etherscan, which means that the money has been transferred/deposited to the IDEX contract correctly - it was successfully mined 5 hours ago. It's not the blockchain. Your money went to IDEX_1.

I would suspect this has something to do with IDEX as a Dapp. [The IDEX FAQ states that you have to explicitly update balances](https://idex.market/faq), so I would start with trying to see if that FAQ resolves your issues with IDEX.